# Psql: permission denied to a specific user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have created two different users on `psql`. With one of everythin works fine but whit the other I get the folliwing:

```
select * from public.document LIMIT 100;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation document
```

And I did for both the same procedure

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to all the users. Login using the user which created the tabled and then run the below script.

`GRANT ALL ON document TO user_2;`

Comment: it says `ERROR:  relation "document" does not exist`

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON public.document TO user;`